# How to handle variable names that starts with a number in randomForest Package

Tags: r, random-forest

In the toy example below, I converted the variable name `cyl` to 1_cyl. I am doing this as in my actual data there are some variables that starts with a number. I am applying randomForest using that formula but I am getting the error shown below. I see that another functions work perfect with the same formula.

How can I sove this problem?

```
data(mtcars)
colnames(mtcars)[2] = '1_cyl'
colnames(mtcars)
#[1] "mpg"   "1_cyl" "disp"  "hp"    "drat"  "wt"    "qsec"  "vs"    "am"    "gear"  "carb" ]
(fmla <- as.formula(paste("mpg ~ `1_cyl`+hp ")) )
randomForest(fmla,  dat=mtcars,importance=T,na.action=na.exclude)

#> randomForest(fmla,  dat=mtcars,importance=T,na.action=na.exclude)
#Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object '1_cyl' not found

#Another functions works!!!
rpart(fmla, dat=mtcars)
glm (fmla, dat=mtcars)
```

Comment: I don't see a convincing reason why a variable name must start with a number. The file reading functions do a good job of sanitizing names and not doing that is just asking for trouble.

Comment: Your options are (1) don't use the formula interface for randomForest, or (2) don't name your variables like that. Since your variable names violate R's syntax for names, there's no reason to expect any function to honor them (even if some others will).

Answer (score 2):

`randomForest.formula` has a call inside it to `reformulate`, for some reason, and it looks like that function doesn't like nonstandard names. (It's also calling `model.frame` twice.)

You can get around this by calling `randomForest` without a formula, but with a model matrix and response variable. When you use a formula this is what happens anyway; `randomForest.formula` is just a convenience wrapper that builds the model matrix for you.

```
randomForest(mtcars[, -1], mtcars[, 1])
```